# How to automatically set environment variable for eclipse terminal view?

Tags: eclipse, terminal, configuration, environment-variables

I use the terminal view in eclipse:
[image]

Every time I start the terminal I run a command to set an environment variable, e.g.

```
SET HTTPS_PROXY=***.**.***.***:****
```

I need this as a prerequisite to be able to download some python packages with the python package manager, e.g

```
pip install mesa
```

=> **Is there a way to automatically run a "startup command" when the Eclipse terminal is opened?**

I expected that there would be some Eclipse setting to configure the environment variables for the terminal or to specify some initialization script. However, I could not find such a setting.

I tried to set the proxy settings in eclipse.ini

```
-Dhttp.proxyHost=***.**.***.***
-Dhttp.proxyPort=****
-Dhttp.nonProxyHosts=localhost|127.0.0.1
```

However, that does not seem to influence the proxy for the terminal view.

(I actually use a portable version of eclipse with EclipseProtable and in EclipsePortable.ini I am already able to specify some extra paths that will be known when I open a terminal view, e.g.

```
AdditionalPaths=./App/WinPython/python-3.7.2.amd64;
```

Also see https://portableapps.com/node/32861 for informatino about EclipsePortable

However, I was not able to set envirionment variables in the ini file EclipsePortable.ini. 
)

Answer (score 0):

You can use your system environment variable.
In Windows search the "User Account" parameter.
It must show your current account, search for "Environment variable".
Now you can set all the variables you need and they will be used by default in any terminal in Eclipse (restart Eclipse if it was running).